# How much does it cost or How much it costs in title

Tags: questions

Here is the title of an article:
How much it costs to launch a new brand.
It is not actually a question, it is like:
[This is]How much it costs to launch a new brand.

I know that titles that began with “How to...” are not questions and there are no question marks and question inversion.
Is it the same in this situation?  Grammarly changes my title to "How much does it cost".

Please help to understand.

Comment: Don't listen to Grammarly here, what you've got is right. That services algorithms aren't the best, and never can be

Comment: Grammarly isn't considering that you're writing a title. Titles are often not whole sentences, and your choice is more normal and sounds better **for** a title.

Answer (score 0):

> [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/how_much)
> *How much*
> What amount or price

> [Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/how-much)
> *how much*
> used to ask or talk about the amount or cost of something

The phrase is not only used in questions. Longman gives examples where it is used in discussion:

• The High Court has also addressed the question of how much information such statements should contain
• An on-screen gauge shows how much ink is left in each cartridge
• With a direct debit the person receiving payment tells your branch how much is due and when
• … a calculation determining how much space copy will take up when typeset
• I wondered how much this contributed to his aggression generally
• Everything gets registered by Mr Sorley so he knows how much work we've done and how much to bill the clients
• I'll get you some paint if you tell me how much you need

Hence, your title is correct and may be understood to be

How much it costs {= the amount of money needed; = the price to be paid} to launch a new brand

Your article may then discuss that price. There is no need for it to answer a question that was neither asked nor necessarily implied by the title.

Comment: Every one of these examples is an instance of an embedded question, introduced by words and phrases such as _shows_, _the question of_, _wondered_, _knows_ and _tell me_.  In embedded questions, we don't invert the subject and the verb/auxiliary. This is not a special property of "how much".

Comment: @ColinFine These are not embedded (by which I assume you mean "implied*) questions, other than in the imagination of the reader. "How much" is often acting as a synonym for "the quantity of". As examples: there is no question in "*An on-screen gauge shows the quantity of  ink left in each cartridge*" nor in "*...the quantity of work we've done*"

Comment: Call it an _indirect question_, or [interrogative content clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_clause#Interrogative_content_clauses), then, @Anton. It contains a WH-word or phrase (here, "how much") whch your paraphrases with _quantity_ do not. I agree that your paraphrases don't change the meaning significantly but they do change the grammatical structure.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already said, your title is fine without Grammarly's corrections.  It could be stated even more succinctly, if so desired.

For example:

- Cost of Launching a New Brand

*or even*

- Cost to Launch New Brand

Titles do not require full subject and verb sentence format.